# Turn off clr option for header file with std::mutex

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, c++11, clr

I have a Visual Studio project that contains files with managed code and files with unmanaged code. The project has the CLR support, but when I add a file where I do not need .NET I simply turn off the /crl option with a right-click on the file:

[image]

I added a class that has to contain unmanaged code and use std::mutex.

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
   std::mutex m;
}
```

I got the following error after compiling:

> error C1189: #error :   is not supported when compiling with
>   /clr or /clr:pure.

The problem is that I do not have the option to turn off the clr for header files (.h), since this is the window when i right-click on a .h file:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: My crystal ball says that it was not a good idea to put this class in a .h file.  Because you are also #including it an a .cpp file that is getting compiled with /clr in effect.  Avoid exposing class internals with an interface.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I have the .cpp file that includes Foo.h. Where **exaclty** should I move all the classes included in cpp files where I disabled the clr option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the possibility to use the workaround known as the [Pointer To Implementation (pImpl) idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29).

Following is a brief example:

```
// Foo.h
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:

  Foo();

  // forward declaration to a nested type
  struct Mstr;
  std::unique_ptr<Mstr> impl;
};


// Foo.cpp
#include <mutex>

struct Foo::Mstr
{
  std::mutex m;
};

Foo::Foo()
  : impl(new Mstr())
{
}
```