# C++ pimpI mutex preventing usage of std::condicition_variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-cli, std, pimpl-idiom

**C++/CLI** is known to block the mutex header when a project is compiled using the -clr:pure or clr flag.
The error is reported here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4d082ff-ce43-478d-8386-0effed04b108/ccli-and-stdmutex?forum=vclanguage

The recommended solution seems to be to use the `pimpI` pattern. See here
[Turn off clr option for header file with std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359179/turn-off-clr-option-for-header-file-with-stdmutex)

The problem I see is when using other `std` functions.
For example consider the `std::condition_variable`

```
mutexPimpI _mut;
std::unique_lock<mutexPimpI> lk(_mut); //Fine std::unique_lock is templated.
std::condition_variable _gate1;
_gate1.wait(lk); //Error wait expects std::unique_lock<std::mutex> as argument
```

Is there any easy way to resolve / work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by forward declare std::condition_variable. 
The problem with Visual Studio's compiler for mutex includes is only for headers. 
Including  in the source files still worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using recursive__mutex class since objects wont be locked.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921466.aspx refer this as well.

Comment: The problem is you are not allowed to at all include mutex if you compile with -clr:pure flag.